# How to search rangeOfString for uppercase and lowercase occurrences?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, range

How can I search a string using `rangeOfString` for uppercase and lowercase occurrences?

This is what I have so far;

```
for (NSString* key in words) {

if ([searchfield.text rangeOfString:key].location != NSNotFound) 
{

       NSString *textresult = [words objectForKey:key];
       NSLog(@"Answer: %@", textresult);
       result.text = textresult;

       result.tag = 1;

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply search for the appropriate `key` in upper or lower case:

```
[searchField.text rangeOfString:[key lowercaseString]].location != NSNotFound
```

and

```
[searchField.text rangeOfString:[key uppercaseString]].location != NSNotFound
```

If you do not care if the user used upper or lower case, simply use the `NSCaseInsensitiveSearch` option:

```
[searchfield.text rangeOfString:key options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location 
   != NSNotFound
```

Comment: or [[searchField.text lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[key lowercaseString]].

Answer (score 0):

I would use NSRange and [NSString lowercaseString] to create a lowercase version of both the search string and the word to be searched.

Then use the rangeOfString method of the lowercase search string to produce a NSRange, then I would then use the "successRange" to output the appropriate chunk of the original text.

Here is a working example I worked up for you:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"key1", @"key2", @"key3", @"key4", @"key5",@"key6", nil];

NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"How", @"are", @"you", @"doing", @"?",@"How are you doing?", nil];


NSDictionary * words = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

NSString * searchString = @"are";
NSString * lowercaseSearchString = [searchString lowercaseString];

for(NSString * key  in words){

    NSString *  text = [words objectForKey:key];
    NSString * lowercaseText = [text lowercaseString];

    NSRange successRange = NSRangeFromString(@"");

    NSRange lowercaseRange = [lowercaseText rangeOfString:lowercaseSearchString];

    if(lowercaseRange.location!=NSNotFound){
        successRange = lowercaseRange;
    }

    NSLog(@"key: %@, text: %@", key,text);
    if(successRange.length >0){
        NSLog(@"    text subStringWithRange: %@",  [text substringWithRange:successRange]);         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
 { 
      flavourarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      imagearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      categoryarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  [filteredListContent removeAllObjects];   // clear the filtered array first
 searchText=[searchText uppercaseString];

    NSString *cellTitle;

BOOL flag1=NO;
searchText=[searchText lowercaseString];
int i1=0;
j=0;
for (cellTitle in listContent)
{
NSComparisonResult result = [cellTitle compare:searchText     
    options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
    if (result == NSOrderedSame)
    {

        if(flag1==NO)
        {
            filtered_flag=i1;
            flag1=YES;
        }
        [filteredListContent addObject:cellTitle];
        NSString *searchflavour = [[categoryarray_ipad objectAtIndex:j]objectForKey:@"flavour"];
        NSString *searchcategory = [[categoryarray_ipad  
         objectAtIndex:j]objectForKey:@"category"];
        NSString *searchimage = [[categoryarray_ipad objectAtIndex:j]objectForKey:@"image"];

        if (searchText.length !=0) {
        [categoryarray addObject:searchcategory];
        }
        [flavourarray addObject:searchflavour];
        [imagearray addObject:searchimage];
    }
    j++;
    i1++;
}
NSLog(@"filtered_flag:%d",filtered_flag);
NSLog(@"filtered:%@",filteredListContent);
searchresult =TRUE;

[itemstable_ipad reloadData];
```

}

Comment: I have used the above mention code for searching in table view. It works for both uppercase as well as for lowercase text.